# How can I make @current_user available in form.html.eex?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'd like to add logic into **web/templates/user/form.html.eex** which gets rendered in `user#new` and `user#edit` depending on `@current_user`. But if I do the following code I get an `assign @current_user not available in eex template` error.

```
<%= if @current_user do %>
  <h1>Example</h1>
<% end %>
```

How can I make `@current_user` available in the `form.html.eex`?

Comment: you can define `current_user` function inside your view and use `current_user(@conn)` inside `form.html.exx`.

Comment: How and where are you rendering `form.html.eex`?

Comment: user#new and user#edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are rendering `form.html.eex` using something like:

```
render("form.html.eex", changeset: @changeset, conn: @conn)
```

And you are rendering the "parent" template with `@current_user` available in assigns.

You can pass `@current_user` in the `render` function in your template:

```
render("form.html.eex", changeset: @changeset, conn: @conn, current_user: @current_user)
```

You can pass everything in assigns with:

```
render("form.html.eex", @conn.assigns)
```

However you should do this with caution, remember explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't pass `current_user` all the time, You can just change the condition to,

```
 <%= if assigns[:current_user] do %>
   <h1>Example</h1>
 <% end %>
```

Otherwise, use @Gazler's answer. both works fine.